ORA-01741: illegal zero-length identifier with sql plus
Hello i m trying to execute this query with sql plus and i get the error ORA-01741: illegal zero-length identifier. Can you please help with it.
INSERT INTO FCCR_DATA_MAPPING(ID_API,DATA,COLUMN_NAME,TABLE_NAME,CONDITION,REQ_COMPLETE,REQ_COMPLETE_EXT) VALUES('compute','customer-rating-rawData-ultimateBeneficialOwners',null,null,null,'SELECT '{ "firstName": "XXXX"' ||', "lastName": "XXXX"' ||', "birthDate": "' || CASE b.typ WHEN 'C' THEN (SELECT to_char(c3.dna,'yyyy-mm-dd') FROM bkcli c3 WHERE c3.cli=b.beneff) WHEN 'T' 
THEN (SELECT to_char(t3.dna,'yyyy-mm-dd') FROM bktier t3 WHERE t3.ctie=b.beneff) END || '"' ||', "residenceCountryCode": "' || CASE b.typ WHEN 'C' THEN (SELECT trim(nc4.lib2) 
    FROM bkcli c4, bknom nc4 WHERE c4.cli=b.beneff AND nc4.cacc=c4.res AND nc4.ctab='040') WHEN 'T' THEN (SELECT trim(nt4.lib2) FROM bktier t4, bknom nt4 WHERE t4.ctie=b.beneff 
    AND nt4.cacc=t4.res AND nt4.ctab='040') END || '"' ||', "localResidenceCountryCode": ""' ||', "birthCountryCode": "' || CASE b.typ WHEN 'C' THEN (SELECT trim(nc6.lib2) FROM bkcli c6, 
    bknom nc6 WHERE c6.cli=b.beneff AND nc6.cacc=c6.payn AND nc6.ctab='040') WHEN 'T' THEN (SELECT trim(nt6.lib2) FROM bktier t6, bknom nt6 WHERE t6.ctie=b.beneff AND nt6.cacc=t6.payn AND nt6.ctab='040') 
    END || '"' ||', "gender": "' || CASE b.typ WHEN 'C' THEN (CASE (SELECT trim(c7.sext) FROM bkcli c7 WHERE c7.cli=b.beneff) WHEN 'M' THEN 'MALE' WHEN 'F' THEN 'FEMALE' ELSE 'INDEFINITE' END) WHEN 'T' 
    THEN (CASE (SELECT trim(t7.sext) FROM bktier t7 WHERE t7.ctie=b.beneff) WHEN 'M' THEN 'MALE' WHEN 'F' THEN 'FEMALE' ELSE 'INDEFINITE' END) END || '"' ||', "localBirthCountryCode": ""' ||' }' 
    FROM abbeneff b WHERE b.actif="O" and b.cli=?',null);
COMMIT;

the syntax is correct, i can't change commas...

VALUES('compute','customer-rating-rawData-ultimateBeneficialOwners',null,null,null,'SELECT should not have the last ' (or maybe you need to escape some quotes, it is not quite clear hat you want to achieve).

that (6th value) looks like a select statement.. so it shouldn't be enclosed in single quotes (maybe in parenthesis)..by the way I suggest to better format the query because it's hard to read hence hard to fix

Break that down into something formatted with each part of the query clearly visible. You may then get an error message with a line number that will tell you where to look. At the moment it's impossible to parse as a human.

Format your code neatly:
INSERT INTO FCCR_DATA_MAPPING(
  ID_API,
  DATA,
  COLUMN_NAME,
  TABLE_NAME,
  CONDITION,
  REQ_COMPLETE,
  REQ_COMPLETE_EXT
) VALUES(
  'compute',
  'customer-rating-rawData-ultimateBeneficialOwners',
  null,
  null,
  null,
  'SELECT '{ "firstName": "XXXX"'
  ||', "lastName": "XXXX"'
  ||', "birthDate": "'
  || CASE b.typ
     WHEN 'C' THEN (SELECT to_char(c3.dna,'yyyy-mm-dd') FROM bkcli c3 WHERE c3.cli=b.beneff)
     WHEN 'T' THEN (SELECT to_char(t3.dna,'yyyy-mm-dd') FROM bktier t3 WHERE t3.ctie=b.beneff)
     END
  || '"'
  || ', "residenceCountryCode": "'
  || CASE b.typ
     WHEN 'C' THEN (SELECT trim(nc4.lib2) FROM bkcli c4, bknom nc4 WHERE c4.cli=b.beneff AND nc4.cacc=c4.res AND nc4.ctab='040')
     WHEN 'T' THEN (SELECT trim(nt4.lib2) FROM bktier t4, bknom nt4 WHERE t4.ctie=b.beneff AND nt4.cacc=t4.res AND nt4.ctab='040')
     END
  || '"'
  ||', "localResidenceCountryCode": ""'
  ||', "birthCountryCode": "'
  || CASE b.typ
     WHEN 'C' THEN (SELECT trim(nc6.lib2) FROM bkcli c6, bknom nc6 WHERE c6.cli=b.beneff AND nc6.cacc=c6.payn AND nc6.ctab='040')
     WHEN 'T' THEN (SELECT trim(nt6.lib2) FROM bktier t6, bknom nt6 WHERE t6.ctie=b.beneff AND nt6.cacc=t6.payn AND nt6.ctab='040') 
     END
  || '"'
  ||', "gender": "'
  || CASE b.typ
     WHEN 'C' THEN (CASE (SELECT trim(c7.sext) FROM bkcli c7 WHERE c7.cli=b.beneff)
                    WHEN 'M' THEN 'MALE'
                    WHEN 'F' THEN 'FEMALE'
                    ELSE 'INDEFINITE'
                    END)
     WHEN 'T' THEN (CASE (SELECT trim(t7.sext) FROM bktier t7 WHERE t7.ctie=b.beneff)
                    WHEN 'M' THEN 'MALE'
                    WHEN 'F' THEN 'FEMALE'
                    ELSE 'INDEFINITE'
                    END) END
  || '"'
  ||', "localBirthCountryCode": ""'
  ||' }' FROM abbeneff b WHERE b.actif="O" and b.cli=?',
  null
);
COMMIT;

Then look at the REQ_COMPLETE value, the first line:
'SELECT '{ "firstName": "XXXX"'

and last line:
||' }' FROM abbeneff b WHERE b.actif="O" and b.cli=?',

Both have 3 quotes and should either be:
(SELECT '{ "firstName": "XXXX"'
...
||' }' FROM abbeneff b WHERE b.actif='O' and b.cli=?),

Note: b.actif='O' not b.actif="O".
or:
'SELECT ''{ "firstName": "XXXX"'
...
||' }'' FROM abbeneff b WHERE b.actif="O" and b.cli=?',

(and in the latter case you also need to escape the quotes in the CASE expressions and probably also want to fix the "O" quotes).

However, if you are building JSON then you want to use proper JSON functions rather than trying to hand code it as the JSON functions will correctly escape strings. Something like:
INSERT INTO FCCR_DATA_MAPPING(
  ID_API,
  DATA,
  COLUMN_NAME,
  TABLE_NAME,
  CONDITION,
  REQ_COMPLETE,
  REQ_COMPLETE_EXT
) VALUES(
  'compute',
  'customer-rating-rawData-ultimateBeneficialOwners',
  null,
  null,
  null,
  (SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
            KEY 'firstName' VALUE 'XXXX',
            KEY 'lastName' VALUE 'XXXX',
            KEY 'birthDate' VALUE TO_CHAR(
              CASE b.typ
              WHEN 'C' THEN (SELECT c3.dna FROM bkcli c3  WHERE c3.cli=b.beneff)
              WHEN 'T' THEN (SELECT t3.dna FROM bktier t3 WHERE t3.ctie=b.beneff)
              END,
              'YYYY-MM-DD'
            ),
            KEY 'residenceCountryCode' VALUE TRIM(
              CASE b.typ
              WHEN 'C' THEN (SELECT nc4.lib2 FROM bkcli c4, bknom nc4 WHERE c4.cli=b.beneff AND nc4.cacc=c4.res AND nc4.ctab='040')
              WHEN 'T' THEN (SELECT nt4.lib2 FROM bktier t4, bknom nt4 WHERE t4.ctie=b.beneff AND nt4.cacc=t4.res AND nt4.ctab='040')
              END
            ),
            KEY 'localResidenceCountryCode' VALUE EMPTY_CLOB(),
            KEY 'birthCountryCode' VALUE TRIM(
              CASE b.typ
              WHEN 'C' THEN (SELECT nc6.lib2 FROM bkcli c6, bknom nc6 WHERE c6.cli=b.beneff AND nc6.cacc=c6.payn AND nc6.ctab='040')
              WHEN 'T' THEN (SELECT nt6.lib2 FROM bktier t6, bknom nt6 WHERE t6.ctie=b.beneff AND nt6.cacc=t6.payn AND nt6.ctab='040')
              END
            ),
            KEY 'gender' VALUE (
              CASE TRIM(
                     CASE b.typ
                     WHEN 'C' THEN (SELECT c7.sext FROM bkcli c7 WHERE c7.cli=b.beneff)
                     WHEN 'T' THEN (SELECT t7.sext FROM bktier t7 WHERE t7.ctie=b.beneff)
                     END
                   )
              WHEN 'M' THEN 'MALE'
              WHEN 'F' THEN 'FEMALE'
              ELSE 'INDEFINITE'
              END
            ),
            KEY 'localBirthCountryCode' VALUE EMPTY_CLOB()
          )
   FROM   abbeneff b
   WHERE  b.actif='O'
   AND    b.cli=?),
  null
);

